# Nginx module for filebeats doesn't parse access logs

Tags: elasticsearch, nginx, elastic-stack, filebeat

I am using nginx module for filebeats to send log data to elasticsearch. Here is my filebeats configuration:

```
output:
  logstash:
    enabled: true
    hosts:
      - logstash:5044
    timeout: 15

filebeat.modules:
- module: nginx
  access:
    enabled: true
    var.paths: ["/var/log/nginx/access.log"]
  error:
    enabled: true
    var.paths: ["/var/log/nginx/error.log"]
```

The problem is that logs are not parsed. This is what I see in Kibana:

```
{   "_index": "filebeat-2017.07.18",   "_type": "log",   "_id": "AV1VLXEbhj7uWd8Fgz6M",   "_version": 1,   "_score": null,   "_source": {
    "@timestamp": "2017-07-18T10:10:24.791Z",
    "offset": 65136,
    "@version": "1",
    "beat": {
      "hostname": "06d09033fb23",
      "name": "06d09033fb23",
      "version": "5.5.0"
    },
    "input_type": "log",
    "host": "06d09033fb23",
    "source": "/var/log/nginx/access.log",
    "message": "10.15.129.226 - - [18/Jul/2017:12:10:21 +0200] \"POST /orders-service/orders/v1/sessions/update/FUEL_DISPENSER?api_key=vgxt5u24uqyyyd9gmxzpu9n7 HTTP/1.1\" 200 5 \"-\" \"Mashery Proxy\"",
    "type": "log",
    "tags": [
      "beats_input_codec_plain_applied"
    ]   },   "fields": {
    "@timestamp": [
      1500372624791
    ]   },   "sort": [
    1500372624791   ] }
```

I am missing parsed fields, as specified in the documentation: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/exported-fields-nginx.html

Why are log lines not parsed?

Comment: Probably this it the case why it is not working (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/filebeat-modules-overview.html):
At the moment, Filebeat modules require using the Elasticsearch Ingest Node. In the future, Filebeat Modules will be able to also configure Logstash as a more powerful alternative to Ingest Node.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you run `filebeat -v -modules=nginx -setup`, it will essentially create 4  things:

- mapping template
- kibana dashboards
- machineLearning job
- filters in the ingest node

Here are the filters for parsing:
- [nginx access log](https://github.com/elastic/beats/blob/master/filebeat/module/nginx/access/ingest/default.json)
- [nginx error log](https://github.com/elastic/beats/blob/master/filebeat/module/nginx/error/ingest/pipeline.json)

The filters are stored in the ingest node. You can access them on:
`http://YourElasticHost:9200/_ingest/pipeline`

So if you want your logs parsed, you need to send them via the ingest node.

Comment: Thank you. I found those filters and used them in logstash, so the end result is the same.

Comment: @UrosK Do you mind to share a file with those ingest filters converted into logstash filters? Thank you.

Comment: The given command works as `filebeat -v --modules=nginx setup` in version 7.x.x for filebeat.